# Inconsistence between CLI command and nautilus units

Tags: command-line, 17.10, coreutils

So it seems *nautilus/Files* and other software are using the **SI** units to display file size for some time now, in *ubuntu*.

But this is rather inconsistent with **cli** command like *ls*, *du*,and *df* that still use IEC binary units.

One could normally use environment variable BLOCK_SIZE to change the behavior of the cli command, but this is not working (EDIT: **here on 17.10**) (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html#Block-size)

```
BLOCK_SIZE=si ls -l -h
```

still displays it in IEC binary units

```
export BLOCK_SIZE=si
ls -l -h
```

behave the same
or using BLOCKSIZE either

Is this a bug ? Has it been patched/removed by ubuntu ?

Edit:
I want to use the env var to define it globally in my `.bashrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like this:

From `man ls`

> -h, --human-readable
>
> with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
>
> --si   likewise, but use powers of 1000 not 1024

and

> The  SIZE  argument  is  an  integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024).  Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of
>          1024) or KB,MB,... (powers of 1000).

I think the commands work like they should, as illustrated by the following examples (running in 16.04 LTS)

```
$ ls -l ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 olle olle 1501102080 okt 19 16:09 ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso

$ BLOCK_SIZE=h ls -l ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 olle olle 1,4G okt 19 16:09 ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso

$ BLOCK_SIZE=si ls -l ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 olle olle 1,6G okt 19 16:09 ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso

$ ls -lh ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 olle olle 1,4G okt 19 16:09 ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso

$ ls -l --si ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 olle olle 1,6G okt 19 16:09 ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Comment: this does not help. I forgot to mention I run 17.10

Comment: I'll have a look at 17.10 ...

Comment: My bad. I was still using -h. this conflicts --si or BLOCK_SIZE=si

Comment: That's right, -h overrides the BLOCK_SIZE=si setting. (I checked in Ubuntu 17.10 Wayland, and it works in the same way as in 16.04 LTS.) I'm glad that this is working for you now :-)